# How to run a function randomly in python?

Tags: python, random

I want to make my program run a few functions randomly. For example, if there's a function, I want it to run 3 times a minute, not at exact times or in a period. It could run at 10:10:20, 10:10:21, 10:10:59 or 10:11:01, 10:11:03, 10:11:49. How can it be done in Python? Does `random module` support this?

Comment: The `random` module does not concern itself with running functions within one minute, but you can certainly use certain functions within `random` to build something like this.

Comment: I'd recommend running a loop and calling `random.choice` with a number between 1 and <time remaining in within the hour>.

Comment: Do you want it to run _exactly_ 3 times in every clock minute, or just 3 times per minute on average (so e.g. perhaps it runs 4 times in one minute, and only once or twice in the next, etc.)? In the latter case, something like a Poisson process would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own algorytm for that.

- get your time-span in seconds (1 min = 60)
- add the times you want to run it in this interval (3)
- create a tast shedduler which is checking the chance to run the script this seccond.
- create a count variable fot counting total runs.
- X seconds before it ends run all remaining calls where X is wanted_runs - counter.

Or you can use this snipped with your wanted data with runs and seconds:
algorytm

```
import random
points = sorted(random.sample(range(SECONDS), WANTED_RUNS))
# sorted because result should be in the right order. now create a timer for seconds in fire call each match.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's rather complicated than I thought :)

Answer (score 3):

In above example, run 3 times in a minute, we could use random to choose 3 time point (in seconds) within a minute, and sort it in place (as MSeifert said)

```
import random
points = sorted(random.sample(range(60), 3))
```

and run functions at the chosen time.

Comment: Note that you need to `sort` the result, otherwise these could be it in arbitary order like `[53, 10, 31]`. Also how _exactly_ would you make a function run exactly 3 times per minute based on these samples?

Comment: Thank you for giving me an example! It helped me a lot :)